# Best way to use html5 data attributes with rails content_tag helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

The issue, of course, is that ruby symbols don't like hyphens. So something like this obviously won't work:

```
content_tag(:div, "Some Text", :id => "foo", :data-data_attr => some_variable)
```

One option is to use a string rather than a symbol:

```
content_tag(:div, "Some Text", :id => "foo", 'data-data_attr' => some_variable)
```

Or I could just interpolate:

```
"<div id='foo' data-data_attr='#{some_variable}'>Some Text</div>".html_safe
```

I sorta prefer the later but both seem a little gross. Anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Rails 3.1 ships with built-in helpers:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag

E.g.,

```
tag("div", :data => {:name => 'Stephen', :city_state => %w(Chicago IL)})
# => <div data-name="Stephen" data-city-state="[&quot;Chicago&quot;,&quot;IL&quot;]" />
```

Comment: This actually just appends things onto my URL. It doesn't add a data attribute.

Comment: Of course it does.... But if you are using a helper which takes both a url hash AND a html options hash you have to explicitly wrap both hashes in curly brackets {}. link_to for example: link_to "label", {:action => blub}, {:data => {:foo => :bar}, :class => "test"}

Comment: This works:
'data-bv-notempty-message'=>"The username is required"

Answer (score 66):

Have you tried using quotes with symbol? Something like:

```
:"data-foo" => :bar
```

Comment: Why the starting colon `:`?

Comment: The colon makes the key a symbol.

Answer (score 11):

A helper's not a bad idea but seems a bit of an overkill for what's essentially me being fusy about syntax. I suppose there's nothing built into rails which is what I was hoping for. I'll just use this:

```
content_tag(:div, "Some Text", :id => "foo", 'data-data_attr' => some_variable)
```

Answer (score 9):

Building on previous answers, here's the canonical way to do it now:

```rb
content_tag(:div, "Some Text", id: "foo", data: { attr: some_variable })
content_tag(:div, "Some Text", id: "foo", data: { "other-attr" => some_variable })
```

Which generates:

```
<div id="foo" data-attr="some variable">Some Text</div>
<div id="foo" data-other-attr="some variable">Some Text</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

JQuery Air (codeschool.com) Level 1, Example 1

Codeschool/platform-independent version

```
<section id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#2012-09-27" data-flights="6">Sep 27</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2012-09-28" data-flights="5">Sep 28</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2012-09-29" data-flights="5">Sep 29</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Rails Version

```
<section id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><%= content_tag(:a, "Sep 27",:href=> "#2012-09-27", :data => { :flights => "6" } ) %></li>
    <li><%= content_tag(:a, "Sep 28",:href=> "#2012-09-28", :data => { :flights => "5" } ) %></li>
    <li><%= content_tag(:a, "Sep 29",:href=> "#2012-09-29", :data => { :flights => "5" } ) %></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can always create you own helper function so then you can write

```
<%= div_data_tag the_id, some_text, some_data %>
```