# Rails - link_to helper with data-* attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to use html5 data attributes with rails content_tag helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258512/best-way-to-use-html5-data-attributes-with-rails-content-tag-helper)

How can I use html5 `data-*` attrubute in my link_to helper (Rails)

The API says that I have to use this format `link_to(body, url, html_options = {})` but I have an error when I put it in html_options

Ex:

```
link_to "whatever", @whatever_path, { class: 'my_class', data-tooltip: 'what I want' }
```

Comment: what does your current attempt look like?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Just pass them in... Rails has a default `:data` hash

```
= link_to body, url, :data => { :foo => 'bar', :this => 'that' }
```

One gotcha - you must surround symbols with quotes if they include a dash:

```
:data => { :'foo-bar' => 'that' }
```

**Update:** In Rails 4, underscores are automatically converted to dashes, so you can do this:

```
:data => { :foo_bar => 'that' }
```

Alternatively you can just write it directly:

```
= link_to body, url, :'data-foo' => 'bar', :'data-this' => 'that'
```

**Update 2:** As pointed out in the comments, Ruby 1.9+ allows this syntax, which is now the preferred formatting:

```
{ data: { foo: "bar" } }
```

Comment: It works perfectly, May I ask => where did you notice of that :data syntax?

Comment: I think it was in a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com)? I'm not sure. I've been using it for awhile. It's defined in the Rails source if you want to poke around.

Comment: I'd like to point here for future visitors that with the new Ruby 1.9 syntax, only the first method works. So, you can do this: data: { type: 'remote' } but not this: 'data-type': 'remote'

Comment: For Rails 3.0.9 specifically, you have to use the direct route with `:'data-foo'`. I might be doing something wrong, but using the `:data => {}` method was putting the hash directly into the HTML.

Comment: data: { foo: {bar: 'that' }

Comment: The gotcha is actually that underscored entities are dasherized automatically. :data => { :foo_bar => 'that' } becomes data-foo-bar="that". No need to quote the symbols.

Answer (score 7):

Add a `data-` attribute by doing the following:

```
link_to "Hello", hello_path, :"data-attribute" => "yeah!"
```