# rails and html data attributes: use dash(-) or underscore(_)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, custom-data-attribute

Lately, I'm facing problems with HTML custom data attributes in my rails application. I user the following pattern in order to add some data attributes to the html tags and use them later in my javascript(jQuery) code:

```
= %a.name{ href: "url.com", data: {first_name: "ben", last_name: "amsalem} }
```

In the javascript code I access those attributes:

```
alert($(".name").data("first_name") + " " + $(".name").data("last_name"));
```

In my development environment it goes well and I get the expected result (the same is true for my production environment in the past), but in my current production version I get "undefined" values.
I checked the HTML source of the page and I saw that I now have something like:

```
<a class="name" href="url.com" data-first-name="ben" data-last-name="amsalem" />
```

Instead of:

```
<a class="name" href="url.com" data-first_name="ben" data-last_name="amsalem" />
```

Why does it happen? What causes the change?

Comment: Looks like what it is now is more correct, and to access it, you need `.data("lastName")` Did you update rails? That could possibly explain the change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734722/rails-link-to-helper-with-data-attribute

Comment: It is best not to use underscores in attribute names. I know for sure in MVC that the Html Helpers will convert underscores to dashes. easiler to just use `data-firstname` for example

Comment: He's right to use underscores here, because you can't use dashes in symbols, and this syntax is really ugly `:"first-name"`.

Comment: How would you then access this data-attribute in a model/controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tests I did: seems like in development I had gems in version 3.2.9, and in production it was 3.2.12 - the wrong behavior (convert to `<a date-last_name/>`) was fixed between those versions, and after upgrading my development version I can see the change.

Answer (score 16):

It's perfectly normal, `data: { first_name: "ben" }` is supposed to produce `data-first-name="ben"`.

The best way you would access this attribute is with `.data("firstName")`, but `.data("first-name")` would also work.

Comment: I agree, it's correct and normal. But in previous versions it was data-first_name, so my JavaScript code is data("first_name"). What made this change?

Comment: As far as I know, rails never generated `data-first_name` when using this syntax `{ data: { first_name: "" } }`, but I might be wrong. Maybe you were using the string version, like `data: { "first_name" => "ben" }`. If not then I have no idea.

Comment: nope, I checked again and I use the symbol version and not the string version. it's a kind of weird, because I'm 100% sure it used to work in my old version and still works in the development environment.

Comment: Are you sure that it was generating `data-last_name`? Or do you just know that `.data("first_name")` was working in your JS? Because it's possible that older jquery version where able to interpret "first_name" as "first-name". But anyways, you should just fix your code and move on ;)

Comment: 100% sure, it was generating `data-last_name`.
I'll update, thanks.

Comment: I am also 100% sure. What is causing this? We just made the update to rails 4 and nothing with user_id works. This is horrible. It will take weeks to work this out of our app.

Answer (score 4):

I take it that you are using HAML. Hypernation comes as default since 4.0. Set `hyphenate_data_attrs` to false to turn this off.

Documentation: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#hyphenate_data_attrs-instance_method

Original github pull discussion: https://github.com/haml/haml/pull/488

Comment: But there should not be underscores in the first place, since rails generates `data-first-name`, right?

Comment: @Robin underscores were not automatically replaced with hyphens pre v.4.0: https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/478

Comment: My bad, I'm so used to the rails syntax, that I did not notice that he wasn't actually using a rails helper, but haml. So yeah, you're right, and I think this should be the accepted answer.