# How to Create a Post with Foundation 5 Reveal Popup in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be able to add a post using a Reveal Popup with Foundation 5 when clicking the add a post link on the sidebar menu. How would i get the form to render in the popup and successfully submit? Then after the user submits the post it redirects to the Posts Index Page.

**Layouts/_sidebar.html.erb**

```
<li><%= link_to new_post_path, class: "sidebar-post", "data-reveal-id" => "myModal" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x sidebar-icon"><div>Add post</div></i>
<% end %></li>




<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>

    <div class="postform-wrapper">

        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
            <div>
                <%= f.label :title, "post Title" %>
                <%= f.text_field :title %>
            </div>

            <div>
                <%= f.label :description %>
                <%= f.text_area :description %>
            </div>

            <div>
                <%= f.label :tags, "Tags" %> <span class="small-label">(seperated by commas)</span>
                <%= text_field_tag :tag_list, @post.tags.join(', ') %>
            </div>


            <div class="submit-action">
                <%= f.submit "Add post", :class => 'small button' %>
            </div>
        <% end %>

    </div>

    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

**Posts_Controller.erb**

```
def new
    @post = post.new
end


def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    tagger

    if @post.save
      redirect_to action: "index"
      flash[:success] = "Post Added"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end


private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :tag_list)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the file: **layout/_sidebars.html.erb** get rendered on many different actions? If so you need to have an empty Post object on every one of these actions.

Your link's *data-reveal-id* may work fine already, but consider using this way instead: [Rails - link_to helper with data-* attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734722/rails-link-to-helper-with-data-attribute)

Can you please specify what happens, with the code you have shown? It will really help in helping you.

Comment: _sidebars.html.erb is a partial that is getting rendered into the application.html.erb layout.  What happens is i get undefined methods and arguments. I need to figure out how to get the posts controller to share everthing with the application.html.erb.  So i'm guessing i would need to put something in my application controller.

Comment: Yes. You are using the `form_for(@post)` on every page in your application. So every action corresponding to a view in your application needs to have an empty Post object, like you do in your **new** action. `@post = Post.new`

Comment: That worked by adding it to each controller action i should have known i needed to do that.  Do you know what i would need to put in my application controller so that i would not need to add it to every controller action i have or would that be a bad idea to do that.

Comment: you can use form_tag instead of form_for. Look at the answers for this question asked on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349348/difference-between-form-for-form-tag