# Link to an Anchor on page in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now I have this link in my navbar. But once I moved things into a Rails app is has not worked.

```
<li><a href="products.html#ultra">Ultra</a></li>
```

I understand it needs to be changed to

```
<li><%= link_to "Ultra", product_path %></li>
```

but **I want it to go directly to the Anchor I have set up on the product page**. How is this done in Rails?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The url helper method can take an `anchor` hash as a parameter, and will output it as an anchor link:

`<li><%= link_to "Ultra", product_path(anchor: 'ultra') %></li>`

From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html):

> link_to can also produce links with anchors or query strings:

```
link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, anchor: "wall")
# => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! One more quick questions. I'm a little lost on how to change Data-Attributes as well. I am unsure how to rewrite this so that it will work.

<a href="images/product/image1.png" data-lightbox="example-set"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401942/using-link-to-with-embedded-html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734722/rails-link-to-helper-with-data-attribute

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't ask unrelated questions in comments - better make a new question, but even better to do a search first ;)