# Use jQuery to pass an instance from the view to the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Environment Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1, jQuery

EDIT: Just FYI, I was discussing the issue the other day and I was told that the common method to solve this problem would be just to pass the record ID.  Certainly, I would recommend that solution in a general case.  In this case, the record is being created and has not yet been stored, so it has no ID and cannot have one until all required fields are completed.

I need to pass the object instance from the view through jQuery to the controller so that the controller use it to render a partial using dependent selects.  This process was generally working even though I was just passing a string that named the object.  But, now I have to implement strong parameters to permit updates and that requires the actual instance and not just the string name of the instance.

In jQuery, I use the following to obtain the instance but it is obviously wrong because it only gets me the string name of the instance.  I assume it needs to be serialized perhaps?  But, I can only get the string name which cannot be serialized.

```
var car = $('select#car_year_id').attr("car");
```

The basic question is, how do I retrieve the actual instance of car within jQuery?  Alternatively, I guess, the question would be that, given the string name of an instance within Ruby on Rails, how do I address the actual instance?  Either one would probably suffice.  Of course, other alternatives will be welcomed.  Thanks.

The form is:

```
<div class="span8">
  <%= simple_form_for @car,
                      defaults: {label: false},
                      html: {class: 'form-vertical'},
                      wrapper: :vertical_form,
                      wrapper_mappings: {
                              check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              file: :vertical_file_input,
                              boolean: :vertical_boolean
                      } do |f| %>
      <%= f.input(:stock_number, {input_html: {form: 'new_car', car: @car},  autocomplete: :off, placeholder: 'Stock number?'}) %>
      <%= f.input(:year_id, {input_html: {form: 'new_car', car: @car}, collection: Year.all.collect { |c| [c.year, c.id] }, prompt: "Year?"}) %>
      <%= render partial: "makes", locals: {form: 'new_car', car: @car} %>
      <%= render partial: "models", locals: {form: 'new_car', car: @car} %>
      <input type="submit" form="new_car" value="Create Car" class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary">
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The "makes" partial is:

```
<%= simple_form_for car,
                    defaults: {label: false},
                    remote: true do |f| %>
    <% makes ||= "" %>
    <% if !makes.blank? %>
        <%= f.input :make_id, {input_html: {form: form, car: car}, collection: makes.collect { |s| [s.make, s.id] }, prompt: "Make?"} %>
    <% else %>
        <%= f.input :make_id, {input_html: {form: form, car: car}, collection: [], prompt: "Make?"} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // when the #year field changes
    $("#car_year_id").change(function () {
        // make a GET call and replace the content
        var year = $('select#car_year_id :selected').val();
        if (year == "") year = "invalid";
        var form = $('select#car_year_id').attr("form");
        if (form == "") form = "invalid";
        var car = $('select#car_year_id').attr("car");
        if (car == "") car = "invalid";
        $.post('/cars/make_list/',
            {
                form: form,
                year: year,
                car: car
            },
            function (data) {
                $("#car_make_id").html(data);
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The controller action is:

```
  def make_list
    makes = params[:year].blank? ? "" : Make.where(year_id: params[:year]).order(:make)
    render partial: "makes", locals: { car: params[:car], form: params[:form], makes: makes }
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!  So excited!

There is a new HTML construct that allows you to using an arbitrary attribute to an HTML element as long as the name is preceded by "data-".  For example:

```
<%= f.input(:year_id, {input_html: {form: 'new_car', data-car: @car}}, collection: Year.all.collect { |c| [c.year, c.id] }, prompt: "Year?"}) %>
```

This is problematic in Rails, because Rails doesn't like hyphens in symbols.  However, there is an optional helper using the data: symbol to pass a hash as in:

```
<%= f.input(:year_id, {input_html: {form: 'new_car', data: { car: @car}}, collection: Year.all.collect { |c| [c.year, c.id] }, prompt: "Year?"}) %>
```

See: [Best way to use html5 data attributes with rails content_tag helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258512/best-way-to-use-html5-data-attributes-with-rails-content-tag-helper)

Then, within JavaScript, you can use the dataset property to retrieve a DOMStringMap object as follows:

```
var element = document.getElementById('car_year_id');
var car = element.dataset.car;
```

See: [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (data-*)](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

This returns car as a hash object, which is really just what I needed!

Overall reference that helped a lot: [Rails 3 Remote Links and Forms: A Definitive Guide](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/)

Just for completeness, I used to following code to convert the hash into an object back in the controller:

```
car_hash = params[:car].gsub!(/":/, '" => ')
null = nil
@car = Car.new(eval(car_hash))
```