# ERB Form text_area attribute name format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, markdown, erb

I have a form for that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(:post, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field(:title, class: 'form-control')%>
<%= f.text_field(:description, class: 'form-control')%>
<%= f.text_area(:content, rows: 15)%>
<div class="actions ">
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 btn-large btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to turn my regular form into a markdown editor using rails-bootstrap-markdown gem: 
https://github.com/belighted/bootstrap-forms/blob/master/README.markdown

The documentation for the bootstrap-markdown is found here:
http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/

It says there that to convert a normal text area into a markdown editor I need to add the `data-provide="markdown"` attribute

I added this piece of code to my template:

```
<form>
    <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title?" />
    <textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10"></textarea>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input name="publish" type="checkbox"> Publish
    </label>
    <hr/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It worked just fine but when I try to add the `data-provide="markdown"` to my form_for erb form I get an error:

```
 <div class="well col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"
 <%= form_for(:post, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:title, class: 'form-control')%>
    <%= f.text_field(:description, class: 'form-control')%>
    <%= f.text_area(:content, rows: 15, data-provide: "markdown")%>
    <div class="actions ">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 btn-large btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

It says there is a syntax error which is created by the data-provide="markdown"attribute

Is there a way to add this data-provide attribute in embedded ruby?

My naive guess it is that it doesn't like the `-` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<%= f.text_area(:content, rows: 15, "data-provide" => "markdown")%>
```

or this:

```
<%= f.text_area(:content, rows: 15, data: {provide: "markdown"})%>
```

to get `"data-provide"="markdown"` attribute for text area. But, it is not just restricted to a text area. You can use the same approach to define `'data-<name>'='value'` attribute to any element in Ruby on Rails.

Tip: If you want to define two or more `data-<name>` attributes then you can do something like this:

```
<%= f.text_area(:content, rows: 15, data: {provide: "markdown", extension: 'MD'})%>
```

Which will generate two `data` attributes: `"data-provide"="markdown"` and `"data-extension"="MD"`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Sorry for posting a simple question but I did not know where to look for this information in the documentation. The ruby-on-rails api docs do not mention this in  the text_area section  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area

Comment: few minutes of googling would have worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258512/best-way-to-use-html5-data-attributes-with-rails-content-tag-helper and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag