# How to write this Rails link_to with a class code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I'm trying to figure out how to write this in Ruby/Rails format:

```
<img src="images/home-dashboard.png" class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-    duration="4s" alt="">
```

I'm not sure how to handle the `data-wow-duration=4s`.

Normally I would write the first part as:

```
  <%= image_tag("home-dashboard.png", class: "wow fadeInUp") %>
```

But what about the rest? How should the whole thing be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just write the attribute name within quotes,

```
  <%= image_tag("home-dashboard.png", class: "wow fadeInUp", "data-wow-duration" => "4s") %>
```

it is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258512/best-way-to-use-html5-data-attributes-with-rails-content-tag-helper)

Comment: thanks so much. This was perfect. I was searching using the wrong terminology and never found this before.